# Numpy , OOP and callables

Tags: numpy, oop, scipy, scipy.stats

I'm implementing a Markov Chain Montecarlo with metropolis and barkes alphas for numerical integration. I've created a class called `MCMCIntegrator()`. I've loaded it with some attributes, one of then is the pdf of the function (a lambda) we're trying to integrate called `g`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st


class MCMCIntegrator:

    def __init__(self):

        self.g = lambda x: st.gamma.pdf(x, 0, 1, scale=1 / 1.23452676)*np.abs(np.cos(1.123454156))
        self.size = 10000
        self.std = 0.6
        self.real_int = 0.06496359
```

There are other methods in this class, the `size` is the size of the sample that the class must generate, `std` is the standard deviation of the Normal Kernel, which you will see in a few seconds. The `real_int` is the value of the integral from 1 to 2 of the function we're integrating. I've generated it with a R script. Now, to the problem.

```
 def _chain(self, method=None):

        """
            Markov chain heat-up with burn-in

        :param method: Metrpolis or barker alpha
        :return: np.array containing the sample
        """
        old = 0
        sample = np.zeros(int(self.size * 1.5))
        i = 0

        if method:
            def alpha(a, b): return min(1, self.g(b) / self.g(a))

        else:
            def alpha(a, b): return self.g(b) / (self.g(a) + self.g(b))

        while i != len(sample):
            if new < 0:
                new = st.norm(loc=old, scale=self.std).rvs()
            alpha = alpha(old, new)
            u = st.uniform.rvs()

            if alpha > u:
                sample[i] = new
                old = new
                i += 1

        return np.array(sample)
```

When I call the `_chain()` method, this is the following error:

```
     44         while i != len(sample):
     45             new = st.norm(loc=old, scale=self.std).rvs()
---> 46             alpha = alpha(old, new)
     47             u = st.uniform.rvs()
     48 

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

alpha returns a nnumpy.float, but I don't know why it's saying it's not callable.

Comment: A callable is something like a function or method, that works with the `foo(...)` syntax.  What do you think `alpha` should be, and what do you intend with that expression?

Comment: You `alpha` is re-assignwd with the result of calling the function....

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, i've changed the variable name to `al`, i've also thought about that but i dont know why it didn't worked out

Answer (score 1):

You define a method named `alpha` based on some condition in an 'early' section of the code:

```
if method:
    def alpha(a, b): return min(1, self.g(b) / self.g(a))

else:
    def alpha(a, b): return self.g(b) / (self.g(a) + self.g(b))
```

and then in the `while` loop (a 'later' part of the code), you assign the return value of this *function* to a *variable* named `alpha`.

Since the names of these two objects are same, and the variable has been declared later in the code, without the function being *re-declared* anywhere after this variable creation, the *variable* replaces the *function* in the namespace and now you can't make calls to `alpha` anymore, because it has ceased to be a function.

If it is not a hindrance to your program logic (doesn't seem to be), renaming the variable to some other nice name would be okay.